# Everit schema dereferencing

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, everit

I have the following schema:

```
String schema = "{\n" +
  "  \"$schema\": \"http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#\",\n" +
  "  \"$id\": \"https://test.com/someSchema.json",\n" +
  "  \"title\": \"test\",\n" +
  "  \"description\": \"test\",\n" +
  "  \"type\": \"object\",\n" +
  "  \"properties\": {\n" +
  "    \"message\": {\n" +
  .............
  "    },\n" +
  "    \"reference\": {\n" +
  "      \"$ref\": \"someRefSchema.json\"\n" +
  "    }\n" +
  "  },\n" +
  "}\n";
```

Also I have separated schema:

```
String referenceSchema = "{\n" +
  "  \"$id\": \"https://test.com/someRefSchema.json\",\n" +
  "  \"$schema\": \"http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#\",\n" +
  "  \"title\": \"test\",\n" +
  "  \"description\": \"test\",\n" +
  "  \"type\": \"object\",\n" +
  "  \"properties\": {\n" +
  "    \"message\": {\n" +
        .....
  "    },\n" +
  "}";
```

When I'm trying to validate some object with this schema, using everit I get the following exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://test.com/someRefSchema.json`

```
JSONObject schemaObject = new JSONObject(schema);
JSONObject referenceSchemaObject = new JSONObject(referenceSchema);
Schema schemaTarget = SchemaLoader.builder()
        .draftV7Support()
        .schemaJson(referenceSchema)
        .schemaJson(schemaObject)
        .build()
        .load()
        .build();
try {
  schemaTarget.validate(new JSONObject(subject));
} catch (ValidationException e) {
  throw new ValidationException(schema, "Error occurred: " + e.getMessage(), e.getKeyword(), e.getSchemaLocation());
}
```

I've tried to add `.resolutionScope("https://test.com/")` but the result is the same.
How should I dereference inner schema correctly, which is located in separate JSON?

Comment: are you sure it is supposed to work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the problem.
Instead of `.schemaJson(referenceSchema)` there should be

```
.registerSchemaByURI(new URI("https://test.com/someRefSchema.json"), referenceSchemaObject)
.resolutionScope("https://test.com")
```